# MYSQL Merge rows based on occurence

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
empid,paygrp,paycode,amount
1      A       1       200
1      A       2       300
1      A       3       500
1      B       4       600
1      B       5       700
```

is it possible to use sql statement to produce the following result?

```
1      A       1       200         B       4      600
1      A       2       300         B       5      700
1      A       3       500
```

Comment: Possible? Maybe. Easy? Probably not. What criteria do you want to use to combine these rows? You haven't really provided a lot of information to go by.

Comment: each employees has different number of paygrp,paytype and amount, linked solely by the employee id, left side of the result is always paygrp A and right side is paygrp B

Comment: Doing this application side will probably be the easiest way. Unless you need this resultset to be used somewhere else within database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two queries for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE paygrp='A';

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE paygrp='B';
```

Comment: sorry, my explanation is not detailed enough, the result i wanted is 1 table with 7 columns, the paygrp 'b' result is merged with the paygrp 'a'

Comment: Or one query and filter the resultset within application. The point stands though - no point building some convoluted SQL for this. KISS rule applies.

Comment: @Swee: Yes, I'm telling you that's not possible.  You need to do two queries, each with 4 columns, then merge them in your application.

Comment: thanks, at least i know it's time to give up. done it in my application but the performance is really bad, imagine 5000 employess to loop thru and merge

Comment: Doing it in SQL would probably hurt performance even more.  Maybe you can post another question about optimizing your client code.

Comment: @Swee: It can be done with dynamic SQL. But I too advise to do it in the app code. Adding `ORDER BY empid, paygrp, paycode` will help your app code to not do any sorting but take the results row by row and either add them in the left or right columns.